# Removing from Java ArrayList without iteration

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment, and I can't find a way to make this work properly. I have an ArrayList with information on 5 students. I need to construct a method that will remove one of the objects, but I do not need/want iteration, as it is a static removal. I have the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.String; 

public class Roster {
static ArrayList<Student> myRoster = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args){

//Add Student Data
    Roster.add("1","John","Smith");
    add("2","Suzan","Erickson");
    add("3","Jack","Napoli");
    add("4","Erin","Black");
    add("5","Jason","Rapp");

remove("3");
remove("3");

}

public static void add(String studentID, String fName, String lName){
    Student newStudent = new Student(studentID, fName, lName);
myRoster.add(newStudent);
}

public static void remove(String studentID){
    if (myRoster.contains(studentID)){
        Roster.remove(studentID);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This student ID does not exist.");
    }
}
```

When I compile the code, none of the entries are removed, and the `else` statement fires off for both `remove` calls.

Comment: `myRoster` is a list of `Student`s, but `studentID` is a `String`, you can't use `contains` or `remove` this way - you will need to loop through the `List` and find the matching record. *"but I do not need/want iteration"* - Oh, yes you do

Comment: Your List contains `Student` objects not `String` objects - see @Tim answer below to use `Map`

Comment: you are adding a Student object, and searching the arrayList a value in collection of Object, this is wrong...

Comment: `List<Student> matches = myRoster.stream().filter(student -> student.getStudentID().equals(studentID)).collect(Collectors.toList());` will return a `List` of `Student`s who's ID matches the requested ID - You can then use `myRoster.removeAll(matches);` to remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myRoster` is a `List` of `Student` objects.  `List` `contains` and `remove` will work against only like objects, not `String` values - it has no idea how to match a `String` against a `Student`.

As an alternative, you could make use of `List`'s `Stream` support and `filter` the `List` for elements which match the `studentID` and then remove all those elements, for example...

```
public static void remove(String studentID) {
    List<Student> matches = myRoster.stream().filter(student -> student.getStudentID().equals(studentID)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    myRoster.removeAll(matches);
}
```

> but I do not need/want iteration

Just so you understand, there is still an iteration been performed, it's just that you're not doing it yourself, the API is

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since we're getting rid of the `if/else` statement, I'm assuming I would have to add an exception statement for the second iteration of the `remove("3");` call, right?

Comment: @JasonRapp Not really, the second call will generate a `matches` which is empty - of course, if you want to display an error, you could check the size of `matches`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though perhaps you should be using a map rather than a list, e.g.

```
Map<Integer, Student> sMap = new HashMap<>();
sMap.put(1, new Student("1", "John","Smith"));
sMap.put(2, new Student("2", "Suzan","Erickson"));
sMap.put(3, new Student("3", "Jack","Napoli"));
sMap.put(4, new Student("4", "Erin","Black"));
sMap.put(5, new Student("5", "Jason","Rapp"));
```

Then, if you need to remove a student from the map, you can use the following one liner:

```
sMap.remove(3);
```

Comment: I didn't include all of the relevant code (as the "email addresses", ages, and grades don't matter for this question), but the assignment explicitly calls for an ArrayList.

Comment: @JasonRapp Fair enough, but for a real world solution a map might be the better choice.  Anyway, the other answers fix your list removal problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.contains(Object)` and `.remove(Object)` uses `Object.equals` to iterate the whole list and find the object. So

- If you insist using `ArrayList`, you should override the `equals` method of `Student`, and the `hashCode` method too, making them use `studentId` only. You should also modify the `Roster.remove` method, making it call `myRoster.contains` instead of calling itself again.
- Below the surface it still is iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of MadProgrammer's answer, there is no reason to open your own stream to collect students to remove when you can call Collection's removeIf

```
myRoster.removeIf(s -> studentID.equals(s.getstudentID()));
```