# Java: How to delete an object from multiple lists at once

Tags: java, list, reflection, reference, runtime

I have multiple lists and multiple objects, e.g.:

```java
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("MyDog1", 5);
    Dog dog2 = new Dog("MyDog2", 2);
    Dog dog3 = new Dog("MyDog3", 7);

    List<Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(dog1);
    list1.add(dog2);
    list1.add(dog3);

    List<Dog> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(dog1);
    list2.add(dog2);
    list2.add(dog3);

    List<Dog> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    list3.add(dog1);
    list3.add(dog2);
    list3.add(dog3);

    List<Dog> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
    list4.add(dog1);
    list4.add(dog2);
    list4.add(dog3);

    List<Dog> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
    list5.add(dog1);
    list5.add(dog2);
    list5.add(dog3);
  }
}

class Dog {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Dog(final String name, final int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Now I want to remove dog1 from all lists, without iterating over all lists (in production I have a large amount off lists and "dogs").
Maybe it is possible to remove all references using reflections, but I did not found something like that in the internet.

//Edit:
It is about deleting the object so the memory is freed. And I do NOT want to delete it manually from all lists with `list.remove(dog1);`

Comment: Are you asking for a database-style transaction, where all the deletions occur together successfully or otherwise none of the deletions occur (having been rolled back)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing from Java ArrayList without iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524813/removing-from-java-arraylist-without-iteration)

Comment: It is just about deleting the references to the object, so the garbage collector removes the object from the memory.

Comment: Or are you asking for database-style indexing to find items in a collection without examining all other items in the collection?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it without iterating? What problems do you see with iterating?

Comment: I do not want to iterate over all lists every single time I delete an object because
1. I have a large amount off objects inside the lists
2. I have a large amount of lists.
Iterating over all of them multiple times per second would be bad for the performance.

Comment: Then maybe you should start by telling us what you are doing that you are storing this same object in so many places. As this is probably where is your issue. And just normal list remove will be still faster than any other weird trick. Best way to optimize it is by just getting rid of that need to store it in so many places. Also how much is "large amount"? Did you check how it affects performance or just guessing? note: 10, 5000 or 100000 is not much.

Comment: **Why** do you want to prevent iteration? Have you thought about using a Map/Set? Is that even an option because of the box you put yourself in?

Answer (score 3):

try to use

```
list1.remove(dog1);
list2.remove(dog1);
list3.remove(dog1);
list4.remove(dog1);
list5.remove(dog1);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to prevent.

Comment: if you want better performance, you can use the Index in the ArrayList instead of Object

Comment: That is not what I want. I do NOT want to search all lists that contain the object (in production I have a LARGE amount of lists). Instead I want to remove all references to the object (if that is possible).

Comment: @JannikEmmerich Then your Question is unclear, and needs a rewrite.

Comment: It can be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524813/removing-from-java-arraylist-without-iteration

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
   Stream.of(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5).forEach(dogs -> dogs.remove(dog1));
```

Comment: That would work, but I want to prevent it, because I would have to iterate over all lists.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `WeakReference`, and then set `dog1` object to null,

```
WeakReference dog1 = new WeakReference(new Dog("MyDog1", 5));
WeakReference dog2 = new WeakReference(new Dog("MyDog2", 2));
WeakReference dog3 = new WeakReference(new Dog("MyDog3", 7));

List<WeakReference<Dog>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(dog1);
list1.add(dog2);
list1.add(dog3);

List<WeakReference<Dog>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(dog1);
list2.add(dog2);
list2.add(dog3);

dog1 = null;

System.gc(); //garbage collect
```

Comment: The idea is good, but it doesn't work because all `WeakReference`'s are deleted when the Garbage Collector is called.

Comment: Only WeakReference would be `dog1` as is set to null